# PHP erro MySQL - mysql_num_rows()

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estou tendo problemas para corrigir esse erro, não conheço muito sobre a linguagem (quase nada).
O erro que aparece na pagina é esse:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\core\inc\user.inc.php on line 10
```

PHP:

```
<?php

function validate_credentials($user_name, $user_password){
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($user_name);
$user_password = sha1($user_password);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = 
'{$user_name}' AND `user_password` = '{$user_password}'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 1){
    return false;
}

return mysql_result($result, 0);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Siga este exemplo aqui, pois acho que você esqueceu do `connection` e sem ele nada será retornado na sua query...

> Exemplo #1 Exemplo mysql_num_rows()

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

Link do [site](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-num-rows.php) onde peguei a resposta.